# A TimeMachine taking my iDevice back to 3.1.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

My biggest headache now is find a iPhone 3Gs with iOS 3.1.2 on it. iPhone 3Gs is everywhere, but all of them are with iOS 4.1 or even higher.

My question is, is it possible that I get a iPhone 3Gs (with iOS 4.x) and some software package so that I can restore it back to iOS 3.1.2?

Btw by saying 3.1.2 I mean the official non-jailbreaking 3.1.2.

Many thanks,

Di

Comment: Why do you need it? To test your software on it?

Comment: @Yuji Yes. I just realized that my app will crash on most 3.1.2 devices, while at the same totally fine on iOS 4.x

Comment: Why does it crash on 3.1.2? Can you afford to weak-link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have your SHSH's saved with Cydia, then you can downgrade to any version you like (that's supported). With that said, after downgrading, You could always not jailbreak, so it's a `legit` iOS 3.1.2, but you would have to be jailbroken at one point prior. Other than this, NO, there is NO WAY to DOWNGRADE from any iOS version.

Alternatively, You can try Xcode to downgrade your device as a `Developer Device`. This would probably be the closest I can think of that Apple would let you downgrade. But it is a longshot.

Comment: Thanks WrightsCS! I'm especially interested in the second method you described. Can you give me some more details or refer me to some documents on this?

Comment: You can download the latest SDK from Apple: http://developer.apple.com. When you launch Xcode, you will want to open up Organizer (SHIFT+COMMAND+O), choose your device and make sure you hit "Use Device for Development" (something to that effect.). You will also need the older SDK's installed, or just the ipsw, not sure which one. You can search google. You should then see an option to restore your device to another iOS version. I would check into the Software Images though, make sure you can find a 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you meant 3.1.3 (not 3.1.2), there is this article from lifehacker on how to downgrade from iOS4 to 3.1.3: http://lifehacker.com/5572003/how-to-downgrade-your-iphone-3g%5Bs%5D-from-ios-4-to-ios-313. I used this successfully to downgrade to 3.1.3.

Based on the article, it looks like you could do the same in downgrading to 3.1.2, you just need to find the right image for it.

Comment: Again, you will also need to have been jailbroken at one point, with your SHSH blobs saved via Cydia.

Comment: @WrightsCS & @donkim: I found from this thread (http://d.pr/dgca) that I should be able to go back as far as to 3.1.3 via Xcode. 3.1.2 seems unlikely if I want to keep my device non-jailbreaking. Thanks for both of you, each +1. :-D