# iPhone App Run Different iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am getting a fat binary when I go to upload, and I want to make sure that my application can run across 3.0, well even 2.0.  Is there a specific way to make sure that this will show when I go to upload.  I am not using any specific iOS 4 features, and I only have iOS 4 in my xCode.  How can I test different iOS version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way as I could think of is test your app on real old OS version devices. Since Apple prefers its users to upgrade to new OS version as soon as possible, they don't actually provide an official way for developers to test such backward compatibility.

Another relevant questions would be, "can I downgrade my device OS version to an old one, so that I can test my app on them?" I once did a research on SO and other Apple forums, and the result I got was NO, we developers don't have a way to "officially" downgrade our device OS version. Yes there are exceptions, you can try jail-breaking and then downgrading.

For jail-breaking / downgrading your OS version, check this post, [A TimeMachine taking my iDevice back to 3.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487314/a-timemachine-taking-my-idevice-back-to-3-1-2) .

**Edited**: It's actually pretty easy to make sure that users with old OS versions can downloaded and install your app. All you need to do is set the **Deployment Target** in Xcode to the lowest OS version you want (iOS 3.0 would be the lowest in Xcode 3.2.5).

However, you need to bear in mind that such **Deployment Target** only ensures that your app can be downloaded and installed on such old version OS devices. They don't ensure compatibility during runtime. You still need to test your app on real old OS devices to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Well my app will be available to users that have the older 3.0, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, my deployment target was set to 4.2.  So that means that only people with 4.2 could have downloaded my app?

Comment: Yes. But 4.2 is a little bit too strict. As far as I know, there are still lots of people stay at 4.1. You may consider 4.0 or 4.1 in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Project -> Edit Project Settings ->  iOS Deployment Target: 3.13. And then build?

Edit according to comment: You still need to ENSURE your code is within the runtime scope, i.e. do checks like 'respondstoselector' before calling methods in question.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't ensure backward compatibility. It only allows the app to be installed on such devices. Developers still have to test on real iOS 3.x devices.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think u need to worry about app version 3.0 below because it is not supported anymore. but how to test on different version, make sure change the iOS deployment target as Thomas refered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no currently supported way to do this.

No current Simulator or Xcode tool will ensure that an app is completely compatible with an OS version older than the SDK used.  The 2.0 SDK is not compatible with the current development tools.  There is no officially supported way to downgrade a device.

Furthermore, Apple no longer even accepts app submissions that have a deployment target lower than 3.0.

Even most old 1st gen devices, if you can find one on eBay, have been upgraded to iOS 3.1.3.  But if you have access to an old device running iOS 3.1.3, you can use that for testing.  Many developers keep an old used iPod Touch around for just his purpose.

People with devices running something older than 3.1.3 are not only a really tiny percentage of the installed base, but are very unlikely to be still buying apps for that device.  Even large developers with staff and legacy hardware available for this testing rarely waste the time on this market.